# How to find list of running application/system software using node js?

Tags: node.js, process, child-process

I want to enlist the running system or application software in node js. I used `child_process`. It gives the all currently running processes. But I want to separate the types of processes.

In this code

```
function isRunning(win, mac, linux) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const plat = process.platform
      const cmd = plat == 'win32' ? 'tasklist' : (plat == 'darwin' ? 'ps -ax | grep ' + mac : (plat == 'linux' ? 'ps -A' : ''))
      const proc = plat == 'win32' ? win : (plat == 'darwin' ? mac : (plat == 'linux' ? linux : ''))
      if (cmd === '' || proc === '') {
        resolve(false)
      }
      
      exec.exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {

        console.log(stdout);
        resolve(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(proc.toLowerCase()) > -1)
      })
    })
  }

  isRunning('myprocess.exe', 'code', 'myprocess')
  .then((v) => console.log(v))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I checked `isRunning` into Linux OS using the VS Code with the name `code`, then it returns true.

The `stdout` gives all running processes. In the processes, I want to know which are applications or system processes running.